# Variance convergence in Kalman Filtering when applying motion and measurements updates?

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, kalman-filter

I'm developing a visualization interface for Kalman Filters in 1D. I have an initial variance $variance\_init$ and constant motion and measurement variances. When I apply consecutive motion-measurement updates I notice that the variance converges to some value that is a function of the ratio $\frac{motion\_variance}{measurement\_variance}$.

The motion update is:

$new\_variance = previous\_variance + motion\_variance$

The measurement update is:

$new\_variance = ({\frac{1}{previous\_variance}+\frac{1}{measurement\_variance}})^{-1}$

I wanted to analytically calculate this variance that the system converges to but I don't know how to approach the problem. It is basically a function composition that looks something like this:  $measure(motion(...measure(motion(var\_init))$